# PHP Random numbers with weights on two levels

Tags: php, random

I have growing number of so called Battles grouped in different Ranks. I want to randomize the battles shown to the user. The show rate to be defined by the Rank at first place (higher rank - more impressions) and the second level is to get a random battle from the collection in this rank. Every battle in the rank has it's own number of impressions.

In $battles I get the battles from the DB and i perform some calculations to define the show rate and the impressions that each rank should get.

```
foreach ($battles as $el => &$values) {
    $values['show_rate'] = $values['rank'] * 100 / $totals['sum_of_ranks'];
    $values['dedicated_impressions'] = $totals['total_battle_impressions'] * $values['show_rate'] / 100;
    $values['impressions_left'] = $values['dedicated_impressions'] - $values['sum_of_impressions'];
}
```

This is the result of the previous cycle.
In the key `battle_ids` i have the ids of the battles in this rank, in `battle_impressions` i have the impressions of the same battles ordered in the same way.

```
 $battles = array(
    0 => array(
        'battles_in_rank' => '1',
        'battle_ids' => array(
            0 => '28',
        ),
        'battle_impressions' => array(
            0 => '3',
        ),
        'sum_of_impressions' => '3',
        'rank' => '0',
        'show_rate' => 0,
        'dedicated_impressions' => 0,
        'impressions_left' => -3,
    ),
    1 => array(
        'battles_in_rank' => '4',
        'battle_ids' => array(
            0 => '27',
            1 => '19',
            2 => '18',
            3 => '17',
        ),
        'battle_impressions' => array(
            0 => '0',
            1 => '0',
            2 => '0',
            3 => '0',
        ),
        'sum_of_impressions' => '0',
        'rank' => '1',
        'show_rate' => 6.6666666666667,
        'dedicated_impressions' => 230.53333333333,
        'impressions_left' => 230.53333333333,
    ),
    2 => array(
        'battles_in_rank' => '2',
        'battle_ids' => array(
            0 => '7',
            1 => '3',
        ),
        'battle_impressions' => array(
            0 => '0',
            1 => '3',
        ),
        'sum_of_impressions' => '3',
        'rank' => '3',
        'show_rate' => 20,
        'dedicated_impressions' => 691.6,
        'impressions_left' => 688.6,
    ),
    3 => array(
        'battles_in_rank' => '2',
        'battle_ids' => array(
            0 => '12',
            1 => '5',
        ),
        'battle_impressions' => array(
            0 => '17',
            1 => '1',
        ),
        'sum_of_impressions' => '18',
        'rank' => '4',
        'show_rate' => 26.666666666667,
        'dedicated_impressions' => 922.13333333333,
        'impressions_left' => 904.13333333333,
    ),
    4 => array(
        'battles_in_rank' => '1',
        'battle_ids' => array(
            0 => '2',
        ),
        'battle_impressions' => array(
            0 => '3434',
        ),
        'sum_of_impressions' => '3434',
        'rank' => '7',
        'show_rate' => 46.666666666667,
        'dedicated_impressions' => 1613.7333333333,
        'impressions_left' => -1820.2666666667,
    ),
);
```

After i get all this information i perform a clean up to get nice result for random function.

```
$elements = array();
$weights = array();
foreach ($battles as $el => &$values) {
    $elements[] = array($values['battle_ids'], $values['battle_impressions']);
    $weights[] = $values['show_rate'];
}
```

Here is the random function that i have at the moment:

```
public function getRandom($values, $weights)
{
    $pos = mt_rand(1, array_sum($weights));
    $em = 0;
    foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
        $em += $weights[$k];
        if ($em >= $pos) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                return $this->getRandom($v[0], $v[1]);
            } else {
                return $v;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And i call it like that to get one random battle id.

```
$this->getRandom($elements, $weights);
```

What i need is having 5 or 10 unique random IDs.

It works but this function gives me only one random element of each call, and when i call it several times i get the same id very often, like 6 out of 10 times.

For example if i need 5 random battles i have to call the function in a cycle with 20-30 iterations to get 5 unique random battles. If the battles in the higher ranks are over it should fill the array with battles in lower ranks, so i always end up with 5 battles (or 10).

The second level of randomization should be the battles in one rank, weighted by their impressions. That's why the random function is recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do this on the database? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM battles ORDER BY Rank DESC, RAND()
```

**EDIT**

If you want to ensure that higher ranks appear more often then I would do something like this. Assuming that rank 1 is the lowest rank and rank 10 is the highest.

```
SELECT * FROM battles ORDER BY (Rank * RAND())
```

Comment: How to set weights to each battle? Battles with higher rank should show up more often than others.